# How to use kartik-v/yii2-editable in a view file

Tags: php, yii2

I have two models :

> Subnet(id,name,...) and Ip(ip , objectid , ...)

in SubnetController I have :

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $ips = Ip::find()->where(['subnetID' => $id])->all();
    if (!$ips) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No IP used yet');</script>";
    }
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'ips' => $ips,
    ]);         
}
```

I want to have all IPs in editable-view :

```
<?= Editable::widget([
    'model' => $ips, 
    'attribute' => 'ip',
    'type' => 'primary',
    'size'=> 'lg',
    'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
    'editableValueOptions' => ['class' => 'text-success h3']
]); ?>
```

But I get error:

> Either 'name', or 'model' and 'attribute' properties must be specified.

I read all [documentations](http://demos.krajee.com/editable)!!! What should I do to list all of my IPs in Subnet view file?

Answer (score 1):

i think you should iterate through the *$ips* variable, since it it an array of *Ip*. So in your view

```
foreach($ips as $ip) {
    echo Editable::widget([
        'model' => $ip, 
        'attribute' => 'ip',
        'type' => 'primary',
        'size'=> 'lg',
        'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
        'editableValueOptions' => ['class' => 'text-success h3']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution worked for me! how can I have other fields of (IP Model) in my editable gridview?

Comment: you're welcome. if you want to make gridview with editable column use the kartik-v/yii2-grid. please refer to https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-editable

Comment: Can I use "kartik-v/yii2-grid" in my view file? Actually I want to add kartik-v/yii2-grid in my "Subnet model" view file!!

Answer (score 0):

It mean is that you must have defined the ip field in model. Have you defined it in model ?.

It should look like this :

```
<?= Editable::widget([
    'model' => 'ip', 
    'attribute' => 'ip',
    'type' => 'primary',
    'size'=> 'lg',
    'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
    'editableValueOptions' => ['class' => 'text-success h3']
]); ?>
```

Comment: I defined "function getIp()" and changed $ips to 'ip' but I get the same error! any idea?

Comment: but the scenario in yii2 is you must have to mentioned the field in rules section which you going to defined it in view.

Comment: It means that I can't have another gridview (from external model) in my view file?